# Logging those hidden stack traces

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, log4j

I'm develping a GWT application with Ebean. When I deploy it to my Tomcat 6 server, I get an Exception related to Ebean, but I don't know what it is. The stack trace is truncated, and shows the message "... 28 more". How can I see those 28 more?

I also use log4j 1.2.

Thanks in advance. This is a copy of the output.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.avaje.ebean.Ebean
    at cl.hyts.secp.server.DataServiceImpl.getSECPList(DataServiceImpl.java:85)
    at cl.analytics.secp.server.DataServiceImpl.getListaHistoricaEvaluaciones(DataServiceImpl.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:562)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: "... 28 more" means that the next 28 lines are the same as in the nested exception.  Was there more in the log below this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NoClassDefFoundError` means that the JVM couldn't find the class class `com.avaje.ebean.Ebean`
and, hence, it couldn't initialize it.

Download the full jar ebean-x.jar [here](http://www.avaje.org/download.html) and add it to the project CLASSPATH.